# Is it possible to get a status from a concluded operation?

Tags: mongodb

In **MongoDB**, you have the command **"db.currentOp()"**, that gives you statistics about the current operation which is running on the database.

Here is the output of the command:

```
> db.currentOp()
{
    "inprog" : [
        {
            "desc" : "conn1",
            "threadId" : "140534427899648",
            "connectionId" : 1,
            "client" : "127.0.0.1:37394",
            "appName" : "MongoDB Shell",
            "active" : true,
            "opid" : 10120364,
            "secs_running" : 0,
            "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(34),
            "op" : "command",
            "ns" : "admin.$cmd",
            "query" : {
                "currentOp" : 1
            },
            "numYields" : 0,
            "locks" : {

            },
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "lockStats" : {

            }
        }
    ],

    "ok" : 1

}
```

Since that there is no operation running on **MongoDB**, the command gives a status about itself, and among the keys above, there is the key "opid" which stands for Operation ID (obviously) and a number: **10120364**

Is it possible to obtain data from a previous operation 1012036**3** in **MongoDB**?

Comment: The server doesn't keep in-memory details for concluded operations, however some metrics may be available via logs or system profiling. What information are you trying to collect and what version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Depends on operation what was done and if you have opLog (your system is replica set; one node replica set is enough).

local.oplog.rs records all changes (insert, delete, update) but not queries.

But, you don't get status of that operation nor any performance data.